# Is it possible to dynamically create Gif files with certain text or images in them using php?

Tags: php, gif

I was wondering if this is possible at all:

For example, I have a list of 100 names. This list is represented as a drop down box.
Now suppose, I have a gif image. If I select a name from the drop down box, the name is 'printed' onto the gif image and the user is able to download that image with that specific name. Is is possible to do something like this in PHP? Does anyone know of any tutorial which I may refer to?

Many  thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Read [imagegif()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php) function. Note that you have to install PHP GD library first. Double check the installation status by using the function `phpinfo()`.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php) is better then any tutorial:

```
<?php
// Create a new image instance
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);

// Make the background white
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 99, 99, 0xFFFFFF);

// Draw a text string on the image, from a name parameter in the $_POST
imagestring($im, 3, 40, 20, $_POST['name'], 0xFFBA00);

// Output the image to browser
header('Content-Type: image/gif');

imagegif($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```